# outlook addin: how to I develop my own one?

Tags: outlook-addin

I am afraid this is an untypical "unspecific" question...

I have a lot of code in Outlook, and this should also be used by other users. Up to now I am exporting the modules and forms from my Outlook, and import them on the other machines. But this of course is quite a hassle on every change.

So I thought about turning them into an adding - easy to do for example for Excel...

I have done some Research now and the following questions are left:

- is it right that the only software really useful is Visual Studio?
- i did download the Trial Version of Visual Studio,  and digged into it... but it seems I can not copy/paste the existing code,  but there are a lot of changes necessary in the code - is that right? Is there a Kind of "translation" for the most common things?

Thanks for your answers,
Max

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if by trial version you mean Visual Studio Express which you can find here:

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2013-express

In any case this should allow you to copy/paste your code. Also if you are a student/academic you can download the full version for free (https://www.dreamspark.com).

If you don't want to use VS, you could try [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Default.aspx) and [NetOffice](http://netoffice.codeplex.com/documentation) as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a series on my blog about how to create an add-in for Outlook. There are quite specific instructions on how to get started, pitfalls I encountered along the way and tips/tricks to help you.

Here is where the series starts:  http://www.midniteblog.com/?p=6.  You can see all the links for the series here:  http://www.midniteblog.com/?s=outlook.

Hope this is helpful for you!

P.S.  You definitely want to use Visual Studio for a project like this because of the nature of Microsoft product integration.